# How to find and count a specific word from text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following XML response which I converted to text:

```
let XMLText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<BlockList>  
  <CommittedBlocks>  
    <Block>  
      <Name>BlockId001</Name>  
      <Size>4194304</Size>  
    </Block>  
    <Block>  
      <Name>BlockId002</Name>  
      <Size>4194304</Size>  
    </Block>  
  </CommittedBlocks>  
</BlockList>'
```

now I am trying to find and count size: **4194304** from the text

I have tried using the search function but it only return the position of the string I am looking for

for example, following function returns 177, which is the position of the string

```
XMLText.search("4194304")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex, this is relatively easy to do.  Make your target string a capture group by putting it in parentheses and then count how many matches it has:

```js
let numOfOccurrences = XMLText.match(/(4194304)/).length
```